# Measuring nuclear binding energy without using mass energy equivalence

Tags: nuclear-physics

I know that one can measure the binding energy of a nucleus using the energy mass equivalence and determining the masses of the nucleus and the nucleons for example using spectrometers.

Is there a also a way to measure the nuclear binding energy relying more directly on the definition as the energy required to disassemble the nucleus into its components without using the energy mass equivalence.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean? One way is to use magnetic field and  measure $p$ and $v$. One example is mass measurement in Fair in the ring using cyclotron frequency. What you want to avoid? I can imagine deduction from neighbours if you study $\beta$ decay knowing Q. Is it that?

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can measure the energy and momentum distribution of the constituent nucleons (for the protons you do an experiment like $A(e,e'p)$, but the neutrons are harder).

The energy part of the measurement is—to tree order—the distribution of binding energies.

You could then *also* apply the virial theorem to the momentum part of the problem modulo an understanding of how the (measured) momentum distributions are correlated with the (needed for the theory) velocity distributions. Alas a bound nucleon is only approximately the same beast as a free nucleon and it does not have exactly the same mass.

All of this represents an enormous amount of work for an indirect and imprecise measurement.

In short, while these things are possible there is no reason to actually attempt such a thing.